# relation between QAudioInput bufferSize() and bytesReady() in QT

Tags: c++, qt, audio, buffer

I am trying to understand the relation between bufferSize() and bytesReady() for QAudioInput class in QT.
Assume that I have:

```
m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(m_Inputdevice, m_format, this);
bs = m_audioInput->bufferSize();
br = m_audioInput->bytesReady();
```

When I look at the values of `bs` and `br` (these are default values and I did not change the buffer size), I see that `bs` is 5 times larger than `br`. So it looks like there is a buffer that holds 5 blocks of audio input data. My question:

Is this a circular buffer? If I have these:

```
m_input = m_audioInput->start();
connect(m_input, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(myFunc()));
```

Then when I perform a read by:

```
MainClass::myFunc()
{
   qint64 l = m_input->read(m_buffer.data(), br);
   .
   .
 }
```

1. Does it read from the buffer in a circular manner? i.e. if I perform read 2 times consequently after a `readyRead()` is emitted does the buffer pointer moves from 1 block to second block (if it has 5 blocks in total)?
2. Is there any documentation on the buffer pointer, and if it is a circular buffer, etc.?
3. Are there automatic read and write pointers to the buffer? Do I need to take care of those, or it is being taken care of automatically?

Any help and pointer related to this is very much appreciated.

Comment: why are so obsessed with whether it is a circular buffer or not?

Comment: I meant that when the buffer is full, the next block of data will be over-written to the start of the buffer?

Comment: I'm also puzzled by this. It seems I always get a 5th of the samples I thought I'd get from a given buffer size out of an IO device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your use case. First thing, I suppose when you call

```
br = m_audioInput->bytesReady();
```

you are either in `QAudio::ActiveState` or `QAudio::IdleState`. Otherwise `br` is just junk.

> So it looks like there is a buffer that holds 5 blocks of audio input data.

A [Sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29#Audio_sampling) is a unit of audio data. If by that you mean 5 samples then it is not correct. There is also no such thing as `block` of audio when it comes to non-encoded data.

You can compute how much seconds(or milliseconds) of audio are in your buffer:

- Buffer size/ Sample size gives #samples
- 1/sampling frequency gives you sample size in seconds
- sample size x #samples the size of buffer in seconds.
- That's in mono mode (one channel). You need to divide by the number of channels

In Qt:

```
   BuffersizeSeconds = (int)((1.0/m_format->sampleRate())
                             *(m_audioInput->bufferSize()/m_format->sampleSize())
                             *(1.0/m_format->channelCount())
                             );
```

Comment: Yes there is a buffer and we are in `ActiveState`. If one captures data from a microphone, audio card captures the data in `blocks`. And by block I mean a vector of for example characters. What I would like to know is that if `bs=100` and `br=20`, does it mean that after 5 readReady() the next 20 characters will be written to the information captured in 5 block time before? Also I want to know that if there are read and write pointers to the buffer so it shows where to write the latest 20 characters in the 100 character space of the buffer, and where to read the 20 character?